# how to get "address of entry point" from exe file in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++

I am writing a C++ application in Visual Studio 2008, and need to get the Address of Entry Point by reading en executable file. How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680336(v=vs.85).aspx) you can access entry of point of any executable.

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_NT_HEADERS {
  DWORD                 Signature;
  IMAGE_FILE_HEADER     FileHeader;
  IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER OptionalHeader;
} IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, *PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS;
```

From above structure [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) having **AddressOfEntryPoint** member variable to access address of entry point.

Following small code will help you more:

```
FILE *executable; 
executable= fopen("YourExe.exe","rb");

IMAGE_NT_HEADERS executableInformation;
fread(&executableInformation,sizeof(executableInformation),1,executable);
```

Note : code is not tested and may have errors.

Comment: @Santosh Dhanawade: thanks a lot. It definitly wil help me.

Answer (score 0):

Find below way to find address of entry point as well as to read various header parameters.

```
LPCSTR fileName; //exe file to parse
HANDLE hFile; 
HANDLE hFileMapping;
LPVOID lpFileBase;
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peHeader;

hFile = CreateFileA(fileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("\n CreateFile failed in read mode \n");
    return 1;
}

hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL);

if(hFileMapping==0)
{
    printf("\n CreateFileMapping failed \n");
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}

lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0);

if(lpFileBase==0)
{
    printf("\n MapViewOfFile failed \n");
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}

dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) lpFileBase;  //pointer to dos headers

if(dosHeader->e_magic==IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
{
    //if it is executable file print different fileds of structure
    //dosHeader->e_lfanew : RVA for PE Header
    printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Matched");

    //pointer to PE/NT header
    peHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((u_char*)dosHeader+dosHeader->e_lfanew);

    if(peHeader->Signature==IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        printf("\n PE Signature (PE) Matched \n");

        //address of entry point
        //peHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint

    }
    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Not Matched \n");
    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}
```